# How can I add more destinations to Alfred's "move to..." results?

Tags: macos, alfred

Currently, when I use Alfred to action the currently selected item in Finder (using Cmd-Opt-), and then selecting "Move to...", the only options that come up are "Desktop" and "Documents". Is there a way to add additional sources to this list or to navigate in this screen to move the file to a different location?

Answer (score 3):

The screen you're referring to is Alfred's standard file system browser, which is described in **Preferences -> Features -> File Navigation**.

A few useful keys for that screen are:

- Use / to go to the root of the filesystem
- Use ~ to go to your home folder

The complete description can be found in the preference window mentioned above, including a few customizable keys.

Comment: AND you can type in a folder name and Alfred will search for matches.

Comment: Use ⌘↓ to enter a folder, and ⌘↑ to ascend out of a folder

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to add more default destinations to Move To, so if the "go there yourself" approach that Ingmar suggested is not workable for you, another approach is to create a small extension as per http://help.alfredapp.com/extensions/ .

I did this to create a "Move to Dropbox" command.  It's just a small shell script, configured as an Action (so you can choose it after you've selected a file) and "Silent" (so you don't get a terminal window opening up), containing a "mv {query} ~/documents/dropbox" command.

The benefit here is that if there is a destination you use all the time, you can avoid having to browser/search for it. I'm not saying you need to do this; it's just an optional approach.

Answer (score -1):

you can just type in the folder name of the destination folder

Comment: Not the question I asked. I know I can do that, but I don't want to have to select the correct folder after typing. I have about a dozen commonly accessed folders that I want to be able to move things to quickly so I just want to have them set up as shortcuts in the alfred window. Kinda like Default Folder X.